# Android Gradle Support Libraries Must Be The Same

Tags: android

App Compat is giving me an error saying

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
```

When I hover over the underlined com.android.support.appcompat-v7:24.2.0 I get - 
"All android support libraries must be the exact same version specifications. Found versions 24.2.0 and 25.2.0

Both of these libraries are 24.2.0..

Build and compile -

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
```

Please shed light on why and not just how to fix, it would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: "Both of these libraries are 24.2.0" -- correct. However, you have other `compile` statements besides those two, and one of those has a transitive dependency on some other `com.android.support` artifact (and there is requesting 25.2.0).

Comment: this kind of makes sense.. Could you explain further? Do you mean they are requesting 25.2.0?

Comment: "Do you mean they are requesting 25.2.0?" -- yes. "Could you explain further?" -- edit your question to post all your `dependencies`, not just those two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buildTools, compileSdkVersion, compile(for libraries) and TargetSdkVersion should be the same!!

Answer (score 0):

Just retype these to be:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
```

and resync the gradle

Comment: @ConnerGesbocker what is your targetSdkVersion?

Comment: 24

I am going the the firebase walkthrough app that google provides so I'm pretty sure this should stay the same. This is what they provided, I may just start the project over

Answer (score 0):

Leave you buildToolsVersion as is (25.0.0). Just work with your dependencies which are the compile libraries. You will always be shown a hint to use the latest version of the support libraries. Usually, you will get these multiple versions found error when you are importing another Android module such as a payment gateway etc into your project. Please do have a look at all the Gradle files in your project.